# mysql - INSERT INTO table from joined tables, updated table has extra column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_cpnllist` (
    `MSTMLSNO` int(7),
    `CLTIME` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`MSTMLSNO`))
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
        INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
        INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM;
```

I then want to update the data in this table periodically:

```
INSERT INTO jos_cpnllist
    SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
        INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
        INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM;
```

The added timestamp column is giving me trouble when I go to do an update:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Is there a way to get around this without specifically listing the columns in the `SELECT`?  To tell it to ignore the `CLTIME` timestamp column?

**NOTE:** It's like 75 columns worth of data, so I'd like to avoid listing all of those.  The `MSTMLSNO` column exists already in the `jos_mls` table, thus it doesn't throw an error.  The `CLTIME` is the only column that doesn't exist in the big INNER JOIN statement.

Comment: I don't think there is a way.  An easy way to list all of the columns to create this statement in MySQL Workbench would be right-click the table and select "Send to SQL Editor" and then "Select All Statement".

Comment: Very true Tom, this will create an already formatted, comma-delimited list of the columns needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using insert, *always* explicitly specify the columns:

```
INSERT INTO jos_cpnllist(MSTMLSNO, CLTIME)
    SELECT <columnX> as MSTMLSNO, <columnY> as CLTIME
    FROM jos_mls AS mls
        INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
        INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM;
```

Listing 75 columns is not that hard.  You can get the list from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` and format it in Excel.

Comment: This is correct a "SELECT *" does exactly that, it selects all. You must specify the columns, OR you can add that column to the other table and just ignore the contents! :D

Comment: But...I'm salary...and that takes time... :( Oh well...thanks for the insight.

Comment: @StaticVoid: Good idea but not an option.  Data in the already comes from somewhere else and can't really be mussed with.  Thanks though.

Comment: @tPlummer . . . By not having the column list and using `select *`, you are just storing up problems for later.  A minor modification to any of the tables or to one of the queries could totally change the order of the columns and produce an error (easy) or unexpected results (very hard to debug).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I got ya.  I thought it verified the column names on its own, not just pushing them through in the order received.  Makes sense.  Thanks for the heads up.